# How can a model refer back to its owner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Given the classes

```
Class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor
end

Class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apples

  def do_something
    #access apple instance here???
  end
end

apple_var = Apple.find(1)
apple_var.vendor.do_something()
```

Essentially, I need to be able to refer back to the Apple instance from a method inside Vendor. I tried :inverse_of but that doesn't seem to do what I want.

I'm not sure how to describe what I want to do better. I know I could pass self to the do_something method but that feels very messy.

Comment: `Vendor` has many `apples`. How do you decide which `Apple` you want to refer from `Vendor`?

Comment: The Apple has a Vendor. I want to be able to call say (where apple_var is an instace of Apple). apple_var.vendor.do_something() and then that method can refer back to the apple instance.

Comment: Why don't you simply pass an argument to `do_something` method?

Comment: This isn't really how rails works and seems quite clunky.  Can you give an example of the sort of problem you're trying to solve: maybe there's a cleaner solution than what you're asking for.

Comment: Ya I'm trying to separate out logic. For a better more related example say a player in a game is a class. And another class is a health pack. The health pack class has all the code dealing with how it works except it needs to know the max life of the player that has it. Hope that is a better example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: And I thought about the arguments, it just felt messy as I was doing it and thought there must be a better way. Maybe I am overthinking it though.

Comment: You can define `do_something` as an `Apple` instance method, so you don't have to pass any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can define this method in `Apple` class, since `Apple belongs to Vendor` you can easily get the vendor object associated with apple

```
Class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor

  def do_something
    # access vendor associated with apple here
  end
end

apple_var = Apple.find(1)
apple_var.do_something
```

**or**

Going your way, you can pass apple id as an argument

```
Class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor
end

Class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apples

  def do_something(apple_id)
    #access apple instance here???
  end
end

apple_var = Apple.find(1)
apple_var.vendor.do_something(apple_var.id)
```

Then fetch the associated apple record using `apple_id`

Comment: Yes I could but it would make for a very fat model that had all of the logic for things that it shouldn't know about.

Comment: Ya as I said I know it could be an argument. That doesn't work for what I am trying to accomplish. But thanks anyways.